# I'm having trouble with Parse Trees

Tags: parsers, syntax-trees

I am doing homework and I have the following problem:

Consider the grammar:

```
statement → assign 
statement → sub_call 
assignment → id = expression 
sub_call → id ( arguments ) 
expression → head tail 
tail → operation expression
tail → ε 
head → id 
head → sub_call 
head → ( expression ) 
operation → + | - | * | / 
arguments → expression arg_tail 
arg_tail → , arguments 
arg_tail → ε
```

Construct a parse tree for the input string:

```
 foo(a , b)
```

Add the production rules necessary to extend this grammar to include the definition of a subroutine. For example:

```
subroutine foo (x, y) { 
z = x + y 
bar(z) }
```

**What I've Considered**

I am somewhat familiar with trees that use expressions,literal, and variables but this is so much more and I can't think of where to even begin. Not to mention create a tree for a subroutine. Could someone please help me with this? How do I even start?

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Hint: use any parsing algorithm suitable for this grammar.

Comment: If you are familiar with Prolog, you could have used Definite Clause Grammar construct in it: it would almost literally translate your pseudo-code into actual code you could run on different inputs to test and see what works.

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually that much more, it just feels daunting because the syntax is different.

### Creating a parse tree

In general, a parse tree is built out of the production rules in your grammar.

A simple string like `x + y` will have a derivation<sup>1</sup> like:

```
expression => head tail
           => head operation expression
           => head operation head tail
           => head operation head ε
           => head operation id ε
           => id operation id ε
```

You can use this derivation to build a parse tree, the root of which will be he non-terminal `expression`, the leaves of which will be the terminals `id`, `operation`, `id`, and `ε`, and the interior nodes of which will be assorted non-terminals; I'll leave it as an exercise to figure out the specifics.

To build a parse tree for `foo(a , b)`, you would do exactly the same thing: find a derivation, and then convert it into a parse tree.

### Adding production rules

This is a slightly harder problem, in my opinion, but still not too bad. I would suggest starting by sketching out what you think a derivation *should* look like, and then add the production rules you need.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is a right-derivation, but you could also do a left-derivation by expanding the non-terminals from left-to-right rather than from right-to-left. I'm not sure how you've been taught, so do what you've been told

Answer (score 0):

Below is Prolog DCG for your requirement (using SWI Prolog):

```prolog
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

id_first --> [X], { code_type(X, csymf) }.
id_rest  --> [X], id_rest, { code_type(X, csym) } | [].
id       --> id_first, id_rest.
space    --> [X], space, { code_type(X, space) } | [].
end      --> [10].
op       --> `+` | `-` | `*` | `/`.

expression  --> subcall | arith_exp | id.
args        --> space, expression, space
              | expression, space, `,`, space, args
              | space.
ids         --> space, id, space
              | space, id, space, `,`, space, ids
              | space.
line        --> space, assignment, space, end
              | space, expression, space, end.
expressions --> line | line, expressions | space.
assignment  --> id, space, `=`, space, expression.
subcall     --> id, `(`, args, `)`.
arith_exp   --> space, id, space
              | space, subcall, space
              | space, id, space, op , space, arith_exp.
signature   -->  id, space, `(`, ids, `)`.
subroutine  --> `subroutine`, space, signature, space, `{`,
                  space, end, expressions, `}`.
```

I think, that it is easier to start with something that gives you feedback as you try to improve on it.  You can test this grammar by typing something like:

```
?- phrase(subroutine, `subroutine x (y, q) { 
x = y
y = func(x + z)
 } some junk`, X), string_codes(Y, X).
|    X = [32, 115, 111, 109, 101, 32, 106, 117, 110|...],
Y = " some junk" .
```

Into Prolog interactive shell after you've loaded the predicates.  `phrase/3` predicate has this meaning: `phrase(A, B, C)` - `A` is the grammar to use to parse `B` string, while the part of `B` which failed to parse will be stored in `C`.

As to your specific question, you can think about it like so: you need a rule that only matches something that starts with the exact string `subroutine` followed by `Id` variable, followed by exact string `(`, followed by the list of arguments `Arguments`, followed by exact string `)`, followed by exact string `{`, followed by `Block` (of code), ending in exact string `}`.

Note that `Block` uses the same principle as `Arguments`, so it's either nothing, a single expression or a single expression followed by a `Block` of code.